Using const defined in generic trait-bound types in Rust
Trying to implement a ResourceId abstraction in Rust such that:

for a given resource kind, the prefix of the ID is constrained at compile time
for a given resource kind, the size in bytes for that ID is constrained at compile time
resource ID for resource kind A is not compatible with resource ID for resource kind B also enforced at compile time.

Before compiling anything, I came up with:
pub struct ResourceId<T: ResourceKind>([u8; T::SIZE], PhantomData<T>);

trait ResourceKind {
    const SIZE: usize;
    const PREFIX: &'static str;
}

impl<T: ResourceKind> Display for ResourceId<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let encoded_bytes = /* encode self.0 to a string */
        write!(f, "{}_{}", T::PREFIX, encoded_bytes)
    }
}

Now, let's implement the resource ID for a resource Foo:
pub struct Foo;
impl ResourceKind for Foo {
    const SIZE: usize = 8;
    const PREFIX: &'static str = "foo";
}

Now, in my code, wherever I want to operate on a Foo resource, I want to accept a ResourceId<Foo> ensuring a resource ID of another prefix than "foo" or another byte size than "8" would not compile.
I was obviously greeted by a number of errors that could potentially go away using the experimental feature generic_const_exprs.
Errors I was receiving:
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
 --> packages/core_resource/lib.rs:9:45
  |
9 | pub struct ResourceId<T: ResourceKind>([u8; T::SIZE], PhantomData<T>);
  |                                             ^^^^^^^ cannot perform const operation using `T`
  |
  = note: type parameters may not be used in const expressions

error: constant expression depends on a generic parameter
  --> packages/core_resource/lib.rs:18:33
   |
18 |         let mut id = Self([0u8; T::SIZE], PhantomData);
   |                                 ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this may fail depending on what value the parameter takes

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors


Other alternatives I thought of:

change ResourceId to be a ResourceId<T: ResourceKind, const SIZE: usize> but this would effectively allow one to define an ID for a resource R with multiple acceptable sizes in bytes as they would simply become independent
implement an attribute macro and use it to generate distinct, not generic types, such as #[resource_id(prefix = "foo", size = 8) pub struct FooId;; seems like a decent alternative, so I'd appreciate some feedback.

What would be an acceptable and (hopefully) idiomatic code design for this without relying on a nightly compiler and generic_const_exprs?

"I was obviously greeted by a number of errors related to the experimental feature generic_const_exprs."—it would be helpful if you showed these errors and the code that gave rise to them.

welcome to the nightly side of Rust.

@eggyal added the original compilation errors, but I'm not very sure they're of any use as the pattern I tried implementing simply doesn't see possible in the current latest Rust.

@eggyal seems like that's a way to go about it, but impossible in the stable version, correct? I wouldn't even be so concerned about using the nightly version, but these features are marked as experimental still. Looks like something might literally change overnight

Agreed.  I had thought you were trying to use those features.  Your latest edit clarifies that you are not, so I deleted the comment.  I think it may still be possible on stable rust, but it gets more complex depending on how much flexibility you require in the prefix.  Can you, for example, limit it to a fixed number of bytes or characters?

Why do you want to store a prefix with each resource id? It will be the same for each ResourceId<T> with a specific type T, so it seems pointless to store it in memory each time.

An obvious alternative would be a fixed size for each resource id, e.g. ResourceId<T>(usize). You woouldn't have the option to use different resourse id sizes for different types, but is that really necessary? If you need a string representation of the resource id, you can always add a method to ResourceId that returns that string representation based on the constant prefix for the type and the bytes in the usize value.

@SvenMarnach I think you have a very good point. The idea of these resource IDs is to be used for API interaction, while the datastores will only contain the bytes as IDs. In thase case, it probably comes to each ResourceKind having a fn prefix() -> &'static str and using that

In general, a requirement that different types do not have the same property can be upheld at the type level by projecting from that property back to the type.  In your case, one might define a new trait, say ResourceKindOf, that has an associated type Kind—and then require that Kind match the expected kind:
pub trait ResourceKindOf {
    type Kind: ResourceKind;
}

pub trait ResourceKind {
    type Id: ResourceKindOf<Kind = Self>;
    type Prefix: ResourceKindOf<Kind = Self>;
}

Of course, this requires that the properties in question be types rather than constants—which makes things a little more complicated for us, especially absent the adt_const_params feature that would enable us to easily create types wrapping a constant of our choice.
The type to use for Id is fairly obvious: [u8; Z] where Z was the previous SIZE constant.  We can enforce that only types that fit such pattern are permitted by adding a PermissableId constraint, where PermissableId is a sealed trait that we only implement for [u8; Z]:
mod sealed {
    pub trait PermissableId {}
}
use sealed::PermissableId;

impl<const Z: usize> PermissableId for [u8; Z] {}

pub trait ResourceKind {
    type Id: PermissableId + ResourceKind<Kind = Self>;
    // etc
}

The prefix is a little harder, as there isn't such an obvious type-level version of an arbitrary string.  The best I can come up with is to use a cons-list of characters:
struct Nil;
struct Cons<T, const C: char>(PhantomData<T>);

Then, for example, we can have a type-level "foo" as Cons<Cons<Cons<Nil, 'o'>, 'o'>, 'f'>.  This is pretty horrible to write however, so let's make it (a bit) easier with a macro:
macro_rules! cons {
    () => {Nil};
    ($c:literal $($rest:tt)*) => {$crate::Cons<cons!($($rest)*), $c>};
}

Now we can instead write cons!('f''o''o') to obtain a type-level string representing "foo".  It's annoying that we need to quote each character individually, but I can't think of a better way (absent a proc macro, anyway).
We can then add the same sort of restriction as before to ensure that Prefix is always such a type-level string.  However, on this occasion we also want to be able to convert the cons-list back into a rendered string at runtime, so let's add a fmt method to our sealed trait:
mod sealed {
    use std::fmt;

    pub trait PermissablePrefix {
        fn fmt(f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result;
    }
}
use sealed::PermissablePrefix;

impl PermissablePrefix for Nil {
    fn fmt(_: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl<T: PermissablePrefix, const C: char> PermissablePrefix for Cons<T, C> {
    fn fmt(f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        f.write_char(C)?;
        T::fmt(f)
    }
}

pub trait ResourceKind {
    type Prefix: PermissablePrefix + ResourceKind<Kind = Self>;
    // etc
}

Finally, let's make it easier to use all of this by creating a macro to define resource kinds and their associated trait implementations:
macro_rules! resource_kinds {
    ($($kind:ident{$size:literal, $($prefix:tt)*})+) => {$(
        pub struct $kind;
        impl $crate::ResourceKind for $kind {
            type Id = [u8; $size];
            type Prefix = $crate::cons!($($prefix)*);
        }
        impl $crate::ResourceKindOf for [u8; $size] {
            type Kind = $kind;
        }
        impl $crate::ResourceKindOf for $crate::cons!($($prefix)*) {
            type Kind = $kind;
        }
    )+}
}

See it all together on the playground.

Wow, that's an amazing typing system lesson and seems to be indeed the only way to achieve this without custom proc macro or the features we've been mentioning. I like it!
